# Accidentally used the word “f’ed” in an email to customer

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior, mistakes

I work as a programmer in a company and we process multiple documents on daily basis.
I was working on one such document and had to reject it since the due date was in past. In my head i was saying “Due date is f’ed up that is why it wasn't processing” and I accidentally wrote “Due date is f’ed” and sent to the customer.
I instantly realized and apologized for this that it was sent by mistake.
Will i get fired?

Edit- The customer said their CSR probably didn't even notice that there was a profanity. Oh man! Thanks for your support. We didnt lose the account and i’m NOT getting fired

Comment: We can't tell you. Wait and see.

Comment: From what you say, if you work with reasonable people probably not.

Comment: Maybe the customer appreciated that somebody has bad feelings towards a missed milestone.

Comment: The company I work for has a 5 minute send delay on all external emails for this very reason.

Answer (score 11):

This is extremely culture based. But even in a culture that is irritated about "the f-word", using it once (and apologizing immediately) should not endanger your job.

There are two possible exceptions:

1. The company looses this customer and the customer claims it is because of this incident.
2. They wanted to fire you anyway and have just been waiting for an excuse.

Edit:
Two additional aspects:
a) Do not dwell on it. Once you apologized, there is no need to mention it again. Same goes for thinking about it too much.
b) If(!!) they fire you for this, their company-culture is so hostile that you would not want to work there anyway. So no matter what happens, you can relax.